# Hide other user comments, but not to admins

Tags: 7, comments

I have created a node, anyone can able to comment on the node. Now, what I want is:

- For Authenticated users, **show** their **own comment only** (not other user's comments)
- For Administrators, show all comments. (I want them to see all comments)

For this functionality, is there any contrib drupal module available? or else show me a way to do in custom module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission View Own Comments?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126826/permission-view-own-comments)

Comment: and this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128914/how-to-view-your-own-comments-without-the-permission-view-comments

Answer (score 1):

[Hidden comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/hidden_comment)

> - Optional field to let users know the reason why a comment is hidden.
> - Disallow edit/reply/delete on hidden comments
> - Optional permission to allow user to hide personal comments (comments on their own nodes). This permission can not unhidden
>     comment.

if you want to do custom edit your node.tpl file add following code:

```
    global $user
    login_uid = //get user id of commnet
    if ($user->uid == login_uid){
      print render($content['comments']['comment_form']); 
     }
```

Comment: ($user->uid == $login_uid)

Comment: `"Optional permission to allow user to hide personal comments (comments on their own nodes)."` but he doesn't want to hide his own comments, he wants to hide all other user comments and leave his own comments visible.